# I need to know more about gedit I am a 10th standard student

Tags: gedit

I need to know many tags to create a beautiful webpage 
   And please help me Ubuntu
       Pleasee
 I think through a video would be bettter

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get started learning HTML and other web technologies [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) may be a good starting point. It is even better than any video could ever be, because for almost anything, you get to try it yourself. Another good place seems to be [the beginners guide on HTML Dog](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/html/beginner/).

For the part of your question concerning gedit, please have a look on the [gedit Community Help Page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/gedit) where you can find all the information you probably need. In time, you may find that gedit is not the best tool for you to build web pages, but then again - any text editor will do the trick for a beginner and gedit is by no means a bad choice.